# Possible to replace values of a config.properties file via TFS?

Tags: powershell, tfs, config

Is it possible to replace values of a config.properties file via TFS?

I need to change the values of a config.properties file via MS TFS, is it possible to replace a value with the use of variables within the TFS?

Example: My automation framework is stored in the TFS and has a central config file with values such as the following:

```
browser=chrome
url=https://www.google.com
```

Can i centralize these values within the TFS, for example replace browser to firefox using a variable contained within the TFS.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you could, just use the Replace Tokens task as your screenshot above. For example:

Imagine you have a file with the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<parameters>
  <setParameter name="IIS Web Application Name" value="__SiteName__" />
</parameters>
```

> This file contains a token called "SiteName".
>
> Drop the Task into the build or release, and then set the Target File
>   to the path where the file is. Then set a global variable or an
>   environment variable called "SiteName" and give it the value you want
>   the token to be replaced with.

The environment variables should use **the name of the token** without the token identifiers.

There are two level of Variables in TFS release. They can be defined in the **Release** (global - applies to all Environments) or in an **Environment** (in the variables set for the Environment).  For more info about about variables in Release Management, please refer this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/release/variables?tabs=batch).

You could also take a look at this [blog](http://www.visualstudiogeeks.com/DevOps/replace-appsettings-token-configfiles-build-release-tfs-vsts) for step by step show how to replace tokens in config files.

Comment: thanks so much! my config file is a  .properties file, i guess i will need a way to change the file in an xml file?

Comment: @xGIx  Sorry haven't tried with `.properties` before. But guess should also works well. You could give a test.

Comment: the token format could be a more standard format like `#{MyVariable}`